# Grails GPARS upgrade

Tags: grails, gpars

I am using Grails 1.4.0.M1 and I am trying to upgrade the version of gpars to use with my app.

So I added in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies{
    build 'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:0.11'
}
```

This however brings me the following exception when I use run-app:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.ClassCastException: groovyx.gpars.ThreadLocalPools cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:47)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
  at groovyx.gpars.Parallelizer.retrieveCurrentPool(Parallelizer.groovy:62)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I suspect it could be linked to the grails framework using this lib in an older version and the versions being incompatible.

Any idea how I could overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, Grails was using an older version of GPars (v0.9), but in a very limited way. Unfortunately it was added to the boot classpath in a way that would be nontrivial to remove or replace, so I reworked that code using regular thread management code and removed the dependency.

If you upgrade to 2.0.0.M1 the dependency is gone and you can use whatever version of GPars you like.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was waiting for 2.0.0.M1 to be integrated with STS. Looks like there is a version that is now so I will upgrade the stack.

Comment: Right. 2.8M1 has support for 2.0

Comment: @Burt how about grails 1.3.8? does it have that dependency too already inside?!

Comment: We're not planning a 1.3.8 release.